# How can I save data on the first few tab and submit the data entered on the last tab using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp

I have a form that that is divided into 3 tabs, I want to save the data entered for first and the second tab, and lastly submit the whole data entered for the form at last tab.

I couldn't find any close example on this, and i'm doing this for a project. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: you can use local storage or jquery cookie to save it in local browser, then merge the data and send it to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store created id, create hidden input in any of your tabs:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'class'=>'idHolder')) ?>
```

To save data from first two tabs you simply do the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'some url',
    data: $('.firstTab input, .secondTab input').serialize(),
    success: function(id){
        $('.idHolder').val(id) //this will save output from controller into hidden input
    }
})
```

And you need to echo ID of your just created item.

```
//this one goes inside your controller:
$this->ModelName->save();
echo $this->ModelName->id;exit; //this will output just created id back to your ajax function
```

Comment: it means i just have to put all the fields input of the first two tabs into the "data:" part?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did a mistake. You need to put .serialize() at the end.

Comment: yes, it works with your way! but there's another problem right after this, it will create a new id every time i click save. how can i assign back the exact id created when i saved just now for future updates?

Comment: @ahua, you need to store your just created id into hidden input inside any of your two tabs. I've just updated my answer, try it.